# Redux selector to sum over numerical values in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reselect

I have a list of objects with the following structure:

```
  const budgetCategories = [
    {budgetName: 'budgetName', monthlyCost: '192', rollOverEnabled:true , dueDate: '02'}
  ];
```

I'm trying to build a selector using `reselect` that will sum over all the `monthlyCost` keys and return a total sum.

## Selector Logic

```
export const getBudgetCategories = (state) => state.getIn(['budget', 'budgetCategories']);


export const getTotalMonthlyBudget = createSelector(
  getBudgetCategories,
  (budget) => { budget.reduce((data) => {console.log(data)}) }
)
```

I've tried a few things with map, but I feel using `reduce` is some how the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use reduce to reduce an array based on logic in call back
Please read through this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
 export const getTotalMonthlyBudget = createSelector(
          getBudgetCategories,
          (budget) => budget.reduce((totalsum, data) => 
              parseInt(data.monthlyCost, 10) + totalsum, 0)
)
```